# Flujo programado en Power Automate para enviar Excel adjunto solo si se ha modificado el archivo

Tags: power-automate

estoy empezando a programar con Power Automate para automatizar algunas tareas repetitivas en mi oficina, entre ellas la siguiente:
Diariamente (de lunes a viernes) enviamos una hoja Excel donde se van apuntando las peticiones de materiales que hace el personal a compras, a una hora convenida enviamos manualmente un correo-e y adjuntamos el Excel. No todos los días se hacen peticiones. Las peticiones tienen una columna llamada FECHA_PETICION.
Como podría programar un flujo automatizado para que a una hora concreta me enviara el archivo Excel por correo **solo** cuando se hayan producido alguna modificación en el mismo **y que solamente se enviara** en horario laboral (excluyendo sábados, domingos y festivos)?.
Aqui van unas capturas de pantalla explicando el problema:

[image: Pasos flujo programado]

[image: Modelo hoja peticiones]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.